# How can i secure my Firebase "subscribe to topic" from the web client?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In firebase FCM i can subscribe to a topic through the web client like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=<your_server_key>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Length: 0" "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/<your_instance_token>/rel/topics/<topic_name>"
```

The only usage i have form Firebase is sending push notifications form the server to web clients that are subscribed to a specific topic.

But how can i prevent unwanted people from subscribing to my topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM topics are not "secure".  Anyone can subscribe to them.  You should not distribute sensitive data over a topic.

If you want to send sensitive data to only certain users, you should be using device tokens to send messages directly.  Either that, or accept the fact that any client can "listen in" on the topic, if they just know the name of the topic and the configuration of your project (which is essentially public since it gets baked in your app at build time).